# what is the subject and verb in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Never miss a chance to make those watching you laugh.

I can not find the ***subject*** and ***verb*** of this sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb is "miss"

The sentence is imperative, and so the subject is implied. It is "you" but in imperative sentences, the subject isn't written.

There are three other verbs, in subordinate and non-finite clauses: "to make", "watching" and "laugh"